# RXJava2 on Android - nested completable does not get called

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a completable method for authentication and I want to retrieve the authenticated user details on login success.

After retrieving them, I want to call an `onUserAuthenticated` method.

I am doing this with a nested completable (2 levels deep), as I want to sent both the authorization token received on `login` and the user details to the `onUserAuthenticated` method.

The problem is that `onUserAuthenticated` never gets invoked.

```
class LoginViewModel(val emailAuthentication: EmailAuthentication) : ViewModel() {

    val email = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val password = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun login() {
        emailAuthentication.login(email = email.value!!, password = password.value!!)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    Timber.d("User $email logged in")
                }, { error ->
                    Timber.e(error, "Error logging in $email")
                })
    }
}

class EmailAuthenticationImpl(private val authentication: Authentication,
                            private val userRepository: UserRepository,
                            private val authRepository: AuthenticationRepository
) : EmailAuthentication {

    override fun register(email: String, password: String): Completable {
        return userRepository.register(email, password)
    }

    override fun login(email: String, password: String): Completable {
        // some missing fields validation
        return authRepository.login(email, password)
                .flatMapCompletable { token ->
                    userRepository.getCurrentUser()
                            .flatMapCompletable {
                                Completable.defer {
                                    // FIXME this never gets invoked
                                    authentication.onUserAuthenticated(AuthType.EMAIL, it, token)
                                    Completable.complete()
                                }
                            }
                }

    }
```

I tried putting `Completable.defer` also only before `userRepository.getCurrentUser()` and both before  `userRepository.getCurrentUser()` and before `authentication.onUserAuthenticated(AuthType.EMAIL, it, token)`, but the code is never reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `authRepository.login()` or `userRepositoy.getCurrentUser()` doesn't produce any items and thus the `flatMapCompletable` function is never invoked. Place a `doOnSuccess`/`doOnNext` at various places (depending on what types are there) to see where items disappear.

Comment: It appears that, indeed, `userRepository.getCurrentUser()` was throwing an exception, which I didn't spot in the logs, although I've been debugging this for two days. Thanks!